# Ajax call is not working in Firefox but it is working fine in IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Ajax call is not working in Firefox but it is working fine in IE.

```
  jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../Chart/CreateChart',
                //url: '../Chart/CreateChart?chartType=Pie&a=null',
                success: function (result) {
                alert("work successfully...1");
                }
            });
```

Comment: are you getting any errors in the firebug console?

Comment: are there really dots in the beginning of url string? does the url really not start with / or something between a-zA-Z0-9 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                url: '<%= Url.Action("Chart", "CreateChart") %>',
                success: function (result) {
                   alert("work successfully...1");
                },
                error: function (result) { alert('error '); }
            });
```

Use Url.Action("Chart", "CreateChart") . I wrote that in mvc2

Comment: No but i am getting values from session using "var used=<%=Session["usedmemory3"] %>;" code but it shows null values during firebug debuging

Comment: i resolved this issue there was a problem of the space IE fix this issue by their own self  but firexfox gives error which is used = <%...%>

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your URL you need to use a GET

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "<%= Url.Action("Chart", "CreateChart") %>",
      data: "chartType=" + chartType + "&a=" + a,
      success: function (result) {
            alert("work successfully...1");
            }
 });
```

Comment: its working in  in IE as stated by the OP, i think the problem is somewhere else

Comment: True, but should the OP not use a GET if the URL he is posting to expects querystring parameters?

Comment: right but may be he doesn't want to show the parameters in the query string in the address bar...

Answer (score 0):

This thread is very old, but I have faced the similar issue and finally fixed it. So I thought this solution might help for others.

You may using asp.net button control instead of html button to trigger your ajax call. Please replace the button with simple input button control and verify, it should work properly.